# How to set one page to not use blog posts, and use whats displayed under page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I recently upgraded wordpress and my theme. Turns out most likely the developer had some things in the parent files that were overwritten during the upgrade. Before, the page was using what was displayed in the Visual/Text under the page settings, but now it's defaulting to posts, and not showing anything else. I've been looking around trying to find the answer, and the closest I could find was by:

changing the wordpress function the_content(); in page.php (or index.php if the theme does not ahve the page.php)

Am I on the right track, or is there a setting some place I can uncheck so it does not use the blog posts on the page?

I am very new to wordpress, and have been unable to get ahold of the dev.

Comment: Please try and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically, I want to make a static page with one of my pages that is not the main page. I want to remove any blog posts from displaying on the page, and instead only show the static information that I have input in to the page > visual/text locations.

Comment: On the screen where you edit the page, you will see a `permalink` beneath the title. This is where you can see the page.

Comment: It is set correctly to www.cagedna.com/features/, but it still only shows the blog posts

Comment: It is likely that you have a category or similar called features and you are getting a conflict. Try editing the permalink to something else and see if it works.

Comment: That worked, so it's a conflict eh...I wonder why that just popped up after upgrading. Checking categories now, is there anywhere else I should look?

Comment: It depends on your permalink settings, but it is most likely to be a category name yes.

Answer (score 0):

when you are looking at your dashboard, go to Pages > Features and then check to see on the right sidebar in the Page Attributes box if there is an option for a Template.

Some Themes come with templates that you can just select right on the page back end so you might see something like blog in that section.  Just change it to default template and it should return that page to a static page and you can then add your changes right there from the page edit screen instead of messing with the code in the backend.

Let me know if this helps.